# What's the difference between adding a dictionary as part of RequestContext or part of render_to_response in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

Currently since I want to access `user` information in all my templates, I always use `context_instance = RequestContext( request )` inside all my views. I also like `RequestContext` because it automatically handles `csrf`.

Right now I usually just put all my dictionary value inside `RequestContext` to render like this

```
request_context = RequestContext( request, {
    'order'          : order,
    'order_comments' : order_comments,
    'comment_form'   : comment_form,
} )

return render_to_response( 'doors/orders/detail.html', context_instance = request_context )
```

How is this different from this?

```
context = {
    'order'          : order,
    'order_comments' : order_comments,
    'comment_form'   : comment_form,
}

return render_to_response( 'doors/orders/detail.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

If there isn't really a difference program-wise, then which is the best practice or preferred method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference, mostly.

In the second example, the context argument updates the context_instance, but that itself is blank so there's ultimately no difference between these examples.

Here's the source...

```
if not context_instance:
    return t.render(Context(dictionary))
# Add the dictionary to the context stack, ensuring it gets removed again
# to keep the context_instance in the same state it started in.
context_instance.update(dictionary)
```

The preferred method for me is using the `render` shortcut from 1.3+ instead of the `render_to_response` shortcut, since for a far majority of my template rendering, I use `RequestContext`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render

render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'foo': 'bar'}) # automatically uses RequestContext
# vs 
render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {'foo': 'bar'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know `render` automatically uses `RequestContext`. Thanks!